# What is the T-SQL Syntax for If This or This then That else Do Nothing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a condition where for a certain ID, when either of two values from two different tables are greater than a number, then I will display a row with both values. Otherwise, I don't want to display any new row. What is the correct syntax for this?

```
if(select 
       a.Column1 > 2 or 
       b.Column2 > 2 
   from 
       Table1 a join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID) 
begin 
select 
    a.Column1, 
    b.Column2 
from 
    Table1 a join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID) 
end

else 
begin 
    Don't Select
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add it as a `where` condition. If your `where` condition fails for a given row, that row wouldn't be selected.

```
select 
    a.Column1, 
    b.Column2 
from 
    Table1 a join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
where a.column1 > 2 or b.column2 > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

@vkp's answer is probably what you want, but the literal translation of the query you have written -- without using control-flow statements -- is this:

```
select 
    a.Column1, 
    b.Column2 
from 
    Table1 a join Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
where exists (select 1 from Table1 c join Table2 d on c.ID = d.ID where c.Column1 > 2 or d.Column2 > 2);
```

This will either return nothing at all if one of records in the join doesn't have `Table1.Column1 > 2` or `Table2.Column2 > 2`, or it will return all records.